# Trouble selecting and extruding specific polygons (python)

Tags: python, mesh, extrude, select

Trying to extrude specific polygons. Instead, it's duplicating the whole mesh. I know some kind of updating is required, just having trouble finding the correct solution.

```
import mathutils,bpy

S=100
c1 =  mathutils.Vector((2/3,3/4,4/5))*10
c2 = -c1

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(o)

def Box(c1,c2):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=[abs(n/2) for n in (c1-c2)])
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.context.object.name="Box"
    return bpy.context.object
box = Box(c1,c2)

def Extrude(box,S,c1,c2):
    epsilon = 1e-04
    mesh = box.data
    polygons = mesh.polygons

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type  = 'FACE'   )

    for c in [c1,c2]:
        for i in [0,1,2]:
            sa=[]
            pci=None
            for p in polygons:
                pci_=p.center[i]
                s = abs(pci_-c[i]) < epsilon
                if s: pci=pci_

                p.select = s

                sa.append(s)
            print(sa) # confirming the correct poly selections

            si = -1. if c[i]<0. else 1. if c[i]>0. else 0.

            movement = [0,0,0]
            movement[i] = ( (S/2-abs(c[i])) - abs(pci) ) * si
            bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value": movement})
Extrude(box,S,c1,c2)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you @batFINGER.

Answer (score 0):

seems vert and edge selection was being extruded too, so they needed to be cleared with `bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')`, and `mode_set` flips to update mesh's selection, and then extrusion result:

````
def Extrude(box,S,c1,c2):
    epsilon = 1e-04
    mesh = box.data
    polygons = mesh.polygons
    for c in [c1,c2]:
        for i in [0,1,2]:
            sa=[]
            pci=None
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type  = 'FACE'   )
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
            for p in polygons:
                pci_=p.center[i]
                s = abs(pci_-c[i]) < epsilon
                if s: pci=pci_
                p.select = s
                sa.append(s)
            si = -1. if c[i]<0. else 1. if c[i]>0. else 0.
            d = [0,0,0]
            d[i] = ( (S/2-abs(c[i])) - abs(pci) ) * si
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value": d})
    #bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
Extrude(box,S,c1,c2)```
````